# Gulp и проверка на существование файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Существует некий .gitignore, который при push-е проекта на GitHub игнорирует .eslintrc.json файл. При последующем клонировании `git clone` проекта, как и ожидалось, нет файла .eslintrc.json, но при инициализации и запуске проекта выдает ошибку:

> Файл eslintrc.json не найден

Как можно осуществить проверку наличия eslintrc.json и если все же файл не был найден, то сообщить об этом и продолжить запуск проекта без проверки Eslint, а не прерывать все ошибкой.

Была попытка реализации, но неудачная:

```
module.exports = function jsbuild() {
return gulp.src(path.app.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(fs.access('../../.eslintrc.json', (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Eslint file not found!');
        } else {
            .pipe(eslint())
            .pipe(eslint.format())
        }
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js))
};
```

Варианты проверки(нерабочие):

```
// по умолчанию файл('.eslintrc.json') находится в корневой директории
// были попытки использовать и '/.eslintrc.json'
const path = {eslintFile: '.eslintrc.json'};

// при таком варианте, скрипт находит eslint файл
// и по идее должна проходить проверка js-файлов
// но по факту ничего не происходит, просто выводит сообщение
// 'Eslint file found!' и продолжается gulp-сборка 
module.exports = function jsbuild() {
    let p = gulp.src(path.app.js).pipe(plumber());
    fs.access(path.eslintFile, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('Eslint file found!');
            p = p.pipe(eslint()).pipe(eslint.format());
        } else {
            console.log('Eslint file not found!');
        }
    })
    p = p.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
    return p;
};

// при таком способе файл вообще не находит и
// выдает лишь 'Eslint file not found!'
module.exports = function jsbuild() {
    let p = gulp.src(path.app.js).pipe(plumber());
    if (fs.accessSync(path.eslintFile)) {
        console.log('Eslint file found!');
        p = p.pipe(eslint()).pipe(eslint.format());
    } else {
        console.log('Eslint file not found!');
    }
    })
    p = p.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
    return p;
};
```

Рабочий костыль(файла нет - выдает предупреждение в консоль и сборка продолжается, файл существует - eslint проверяет js файл):

```
module.exports = function jsbuild() {
    let p = gulp.src(path.app.js).pipe(plumber());
    try {
        if (fs.accessSync(path.eslintFile)) {
            p = p.pipe(eslint()).pipe(eslint.format());
        }
        p = p.pipe(eslint()).pipe(eslint.format());
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Eslint not found')
    }
    p = p.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
    return p;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать решить проблему "в лоб"

```js
module.exports = function jsbuild() {
  let p = gulp.src(path.app.js).pipe(plumber());
  if (fs.accessSync('../../.eslintrc.json')) {
    p = p.pipe(eslint()).pipe(eslint.format());
  }
  p = p.pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js));
  return p;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вот в чем проблема, если использовать fs.accessSync то проверка не проходит(файл не найден), но если использовать fs.access файл находит, но   не подключает .pipe(eslint()). Примеры с комментариями были добавлены в тело вопроса

Comment: оберни в try catch и не парься